# Cannot open assembly...File does not contain a valid CIL image

Tags: macos, mono-framework

I am on Mac OS X 10.7.5. and I am trying to run an executable called G.R.O.exe. 
I downloaded the mono framework to do this but it when I try to execute the file I get this error:

```
Cannot open assembly 'G.R.O.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

Please help i am rather newbish at these things so please put everything in stupid terms... or at least teach me a bit.

Comment: Are you sure it's a .NET exe? What application is that?

Comment: I think so. Its also a game download from the internet